# Take the value of a column if the query column matches a condition - linux

Tags: linux

So i have a file with column that has information on salary (eg. 2674 dollars) -

```
   indi  salary
   sam    2674
   john   6375
   max    9547
```

and another file with the scale of the salary (column1&colum2) on its corresponding rank (column3)

```
salary_min salary_max Rank
2000           4000    Deputy
4000           6000    secretary
6000           8000    Assistant
8000           10000   Manager
```

Now I would like to assign those individuals from file 1 based on the salary to their corresponding rank

so the final output would be

```
indi    Rank
 sam    Deputy
 john   Assistant
 max    Manager
```

How can I achieve this in linux on the same dataset type but with larger data.
Thanks for suggestions
M

Comment: So, do you want this in linux? in R? or in R on linux? and if it's the latter what difference does it make than running it on a different OS?

Comment: it will be great if it is in R - (can run it in personal computer) and see it - and then I can use the Rcode to submit as a job script in linux - as the data is huge

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me

```
awk '{ a[$1] = a[$1] "$2 >= " $2 " && $2 <= " $3 " ? \"" $4 "\" : "; } END { for (i in a) print "$1 == \"" i "\" {

print $0 \"\t\" (" a[i] "\"\"); }"; }' file2.txt > tmp.awk awk -f tmp.awk file1.txt > newfile.txt
```